# Permission in android

Tags: java, android, permissions

I need to run my app and ask about read external storage permission, I'm using `RecyclerView` and when I accept perrmission it shows just empty app without items, I have to run app second time to see my list of items
How can I draw items in recycler view right when user accept the permission?

Here is my on create method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
        }
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try{
        intent = new Intent(Broadcast_SEEKBAR);

        loadAudio();
        initRW();
        initViews();
        setListeners();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}
```

and here is initialization of recycler view

```
   private void initRW() {
    if (audioList.size() > 0) {
        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        rwa = new RWAdapter(audioList, getApplicationContext());
        rv.setAdapter(rwa);
        rv.addOnItemTouchListener(new MyTouchListener(this, new onItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int index) {
                playAudio(index);
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

and here is onRequestPermissionsResult method

```
    @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {

        case 0: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to call below methods again if user grants permission

```
loadAudio();
initRW();
```

Also in onCreate() call above two methods only if permissions are granted

Comment: do you know why is this happening if i decline twice? "RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout"

Comment: I didn't get you issue. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I decline permission once and than i open app again and accept permission or decline, and my log says that

Comment: I did n't get your problem, Can you share your code or create a sample?

Answer (score 1):

Call `initRW` inside `onRequestPermissionsResult` when permission is granted

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {

        case 0: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                initRW();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
            return;
        }
    }

}
```